# Java UDP torrent tracker scrape request?

Tags: java, udp, bittorrent, tracker

Does anyone have any snippets / pieces of code that can do a UDP tracker scrape? I have the scrape UDP URL, and a list of infohashes, but have no idea how to send and receive the scrape request.

Answer (score 1):

How about using one of the BitTorrent libraries written in Java?
There's [TTorrent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent) and [bt](https://github.com/atomashpolskiy/bt). At a glance, both seem to support UDP trackers. For instance, in ttorrent there's a `UDPTrackerClient` class